# java get sorted values from immutablemap based on list of keys

Tags: java

I have `ImmutableMap<String, Integer>` and `List<String>` that defines the order. I want to get `ImmutableList<Integer>` with that order. For example:

```
map (<"a", 66>, <"kk", 2>, <"m", 8>) 

list ["kk", "m", "a"]
```

As result I want another list of values from given list with defined order :`[2, 8, 66].`

What is the best way to do it in java?

Comment: loop over the keys, get values from map, add them to a new list?

Comment: What's the current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<>(map.size());
for(String l : list) {
    numbers.add(map.get(l));
}
```

example from **Java 8** streams

```
List<Integer> numbers= list.stream().map(map::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Java SE 8 to the rescue! The Java API comes with a new abstraction called Stream that lets you process data in a declarative way. Streams can leverage multi-core architectures without you having to write a single line of multithread code.

Comment: This is redundant. Why are you just copying the other answer? You could at least give more explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Without streams you can use a simple for loop:

```
List<Integer> valuesInOrder = new ArrayList<>(map.size());
for(String s : list) {
    valuesInOrder.add(map.get(s));
}
```

If you want to use streams you could do:

```
List<Integer> valuesInOrder =
    list.stream().map(map::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```